# How shall I diagnose memory leakage in this long-running java program?

Tags: java, performance, memory, memory-leaks, profiling

I have tried to use jmap / eclipse / jvisualvm etc. to diagnose the problem, but did not make much progress. Any of your suggestions will be appreicated!

We have a long running java app that memory leakage issue. We use the following setting for starting the program. We use java 1.7.0_67.

```
java -server -Xmx500M -Xms500M -XX:NewSize=300M \
     -verbosegc -Xloggc:/var/log/singer/gc.log -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation \
     -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=100 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2M -XX:+PrintGCDetails \
     -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintClassHistogram \
     -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC
```

After running for a few days, "top -p" will show something as follows:

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                               
29503 root      35  15 8240m 1.2g  14m S   36  2.0 215:31.18 java
```

'top' command shows that the resident memory usage for our program is 1.2G. It is way more than the 500M max heap size that we set.

The following shows some jvm metrics.The count is no where near 1.2G. The program does not have use this much memory when it starts.

```
jvm_gc_ConcurrentMarkSweep_cycles: 5
jvm_gc_ConcurrentMarkSweep_msec: 110
jvm_gc_ParNew_cycles: 26129
jvm_gc_ParNew_msec: 130964
jvm_gc_cycles: 26134
jvm_gc_msec: 131074    
jvm_buffer_direct_count: 27
jvm_buffer_direct_max: 463077
jvm_buffer_direct_used: 463077
jvm_buffer_mapped_count: 0
jvm_buffer_mapped_max: 0
jvm_buffer_mapped_used: 0
jvm_classes_current_loaded: 2821
jvm_classes_total_loaded: 2821
jvm_classes_total_unloaded: 0
jvm_compilation_time_msec: 12976
jvm_current_mem_CMS_Old_Gen_max: 209715200
jvm_current_mem_CMS_Old_Gen_used: 82458736
jvm_current_mem_CMS_Perm_Gen_max: 85983232
jvm_current_mem_CMS_Perm_Gen_used: 20445832
jvm_current_mem_Code_Cache_max: 50331648
jvm_current_mem_Code_Cache_used: 4465792
jvm_current_mem_Par_Eden_Space_max: 251658240
jvm_current_mem_Par_Eden_Space_used: 131968344
jvm_current_mem_Par_Survivor_Space_max: 31457280
jvm_current_mem_Par_Survivor_Space_used: 2681328
jvm_current_mem_used: 242020032
jvm_fd_count: 493
jvm_fd_limit: 65536
jvm_heap_committed: 492830720
jvm_heap_max: 492830720
jvm_heap_used: 217095032
jvm_nonheap_committed: 38780928
jvm_nonheap_max: 136314880
jvm_nonheap_used: 24911624
jvm_num_cpus: 32
jvm_post_gc_CMS_Old_Gen_max: 209715200
jvm_post_gc_CMS_Old_Gen_used: 13095808
jvm_post_gc_CMS_Perm_Gen_max: 85983232
jvm_post_gc_CMS_Perm_Gen_used: 20444448
jvm_post_gc_Par_Eden_Space_max: 251658240
jvm_post_gc_Par_Eden_Space_used: 0
jvm_post_gc_Par_Survivor_Space_max: 31457280
jvm_post_gc_Par_Survivor_Space_used: 2681328
jvm_post_gc_used: 36221584
jvm_start_time: 1440568584192
jvm_thread_count: 65
jvm_thread_daemon_count: 25
jvm_thread_peak_count: 79
jvm_uptime: 50765537
```

The process status:

```
Name:   java
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   29503
Ngid:   0
Pid:    29503
PPid:   1
TracerPid:  0
Uid:    0   0   0   0
Gid:    0   0   0   0
FDSize: 1024
Groups: 0 
VmPeak:  8440764 kB
VmSize:  8439440 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM:   1232168 kB
VmRSS:   1232168 kB
VmData:  8386608 kB
VmStk:       136 kB
VmExe:         4 kB
VmLib:     15320 kB
VmPTE:      3296 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
Threads:    104
SigQ:   0/241457
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
ShdPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000000000
SigIgn: 0000000000000002
SigCgt: 2000000181005ccd
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 0000003fffffffff
CapEff: 0000003fffffffff
CapBnd: 0000003fffffffff
Seccomp:    0
Cpus_allowed:   ffffffff,ffffffff,ffffffff,ffffffff
Cpus_allowed_list:  0-127
Mems_allowed:   00000000,00000003
Mems_allowed_list:  0-1 
voluntary_ctxt_switches:    52
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches: 2
```

Answer (score 2):

This HAS to be a dupe, but let me give you a quick tip

First of all you need a profiler of some sort.  There are quite a few to choose from that can do this.  Get the profiler to run against your app, then do the following:

- Run 2 garbage collections (The profiler can do this)
- Create a dump that saves the count of your classes
- Let your program run a while, long enough to lose some memory
- Run 2 garbage collections again
- Make a second dump
- Diff the two dumps  (there should be a function in the profiler that gives you class count increase since the first dump making this really easy)

What you are looking for is a class count that increase dramatically for one or more classes.  Once you find this all you have to do is figure out what is referring to (Holding a reference to) that class (Should also be in your dump somewhere), that's your leak.  When there is more than one class increasing in number, look for the root one that contains references to the others--that's the one you have to free.

It's not your VM settings or anything like that, just a simple programming bug somewhere keeping references that you thought were freed--Like adding a listener without removing it or forgetting to dispose of frames.

Comment: I have taken a few dumps of the process using jmap, and used eclipse memory analyzer to analyze it. The interesting part is that the eclipse memory analyzer reports much smaller heap memory usage than what we observe using top.

Comment: The Jim uses a lot of memory, you can't go off of any one time measurements, you need to look for a difference in class counts.

Comment: I might miss something, could you explain 'Jim'?  Could you also suggest some profilers that I can use?  Jprofiler requires a license and I do not have one.

Comment: Sorry, Phone typo--I meant that the JVM can use a lot of memory that will show up in PS but not in eclipse, so memory isn't a good indication of a problem.  VisualVM is a little harder than jprofiler but should be able to give you instance counts (and it is distributed with the JDK).

Comment: thanks! i have some problem with visualvm -- the program runs remotely on the host, and it does not have gui support. I tried with jstatd, and haven't got it work so far.

Answer (score 1):

In order to find a leak we usually use combination of JMeter/VisualVM heap dumps. Procedure is the following:

- launch test app & connect to JVM with profiler (in our case VisulaVM)
- start JMeter script to emulate real app usage
- Start Sampler in visual VM, if app is big create memory dump and analyze it separately. Inside the dump - look at *number of bytes* and *number of class instances created* for your application. Initially, pay attention to your application specific classes.

Based on details provided in your description it is hard to say where the root cause of the leak. You should know your app better (it might be session beans which are not cleaned up by GC, etc), but as I mentioned memory dump is a good thing to start with.

For real production app servers it's always good to have JMX configured in order to troubleshoot these kind of problems later on.

One of the [articles to start with](http://developerblog.redhat.com/2014/08/14/find-fix-memory-leaks-java-application/).